# Order of composite where clause (MySQL, Postgres)

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, indexing

I have a `table t` with columns `a int, b int, c int`; composite `index i (b, c)`. I fetch some data with following query:

```
select * from t where c = 1 and b = 2;
```

So the question is: will MySQL and Postgres use the index `i`? And, more generally: does the query composite where clause order affect the possibility of index use?

Comment: Use EXPLAIN to see what query plan your database creates.

Comment: yes you are right. It works differently. Am deleting my answer. Thanks for the reference!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use the explain function in both, to see what's going on. If it says it's using an  index then it is. One caveat is that in a small table with minimal data, it's very likely that postgresql (and probably mysql) will ignore the indexes and favor of a scan. To get a real result, insert quite a bit of dummy data (at least 20 rows, and I always do about 500) and be sure the analyze the table. Also, realize that if the search criteria will return a large percentage of the table results, it will likely not use the index either (as a scan will be faster).

1. create table
2. generate data (perhaps using generate_series)
3. run `explain select * from t where c=1 and b=2`
4. create index `create index on t(b,c)
5. Analyze table `analyze t`
6. run `explain select * from t where c=1 and b=2` and compare with first run

hopefully this will help answer this, and other questions you might have in the future about when indexes will run. To answer your original question though, yes, in general postgresql will use the index, regardless of order, if the optimizer determines that to be the best way to get your results. Remember to analyze your table though, so the optimizer has an idea of what information is in your table, and analyze it any time a ton of data is added or deleted from your table. Depending on your PG version and settings, some of this may be done automatically for you, but it won't hurt to manually analyze, especially when testing this kind of thing.

Edit: the index order may (especially if you don't use an order by in your query and the optimizer uses the index) effect the order of the results of your query-- the returned rows may be ordered in the same order of the index.

Answer (score 1):

It's not, the order doesn't matter.

Optimizer does a lot of smart things to perform a query in the most efficient way.